# "Israeli-like" or "Israel-like"?

Tags: word-usage, suffixes, construction

I happened upon an old news footage in which Howard K. Smith said,

> [C]ivilized people are going to have to accept much more police security action and put up much tougher resistance, **Israeli-like**, until the fashion dies out or is discredited by defeat.

But I recall that the suffix **-like** should be attached to nouns to form such words as *pealike* and *ladylike*, as confirmed by the ODO.

> (added to nouns) similar to; characteristic of.

So is the correct usage **Israeli-like** or **Israel-like**?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between *Israeli* and *Israel*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Israeli" is a single citizen of Israel.  It is also an adjective.

"Israeli-like"  is characteristic of an Israeli.
"Israel-like" is characteristic of Israel.